# Debugging dynamically compiled code with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using `Roslyn` to dynamically compile arbitrary `*.cs` files. I am able to generate the `DLLs` and `PDBs` and execute methods within the loaded assemblies via reflection, but when attaching the VS debugger from `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`, I'm getting 'source not available' errors. The 'Modules' windows in VS shows that the symbols have been loaded successfully. The source in question lives in a project under the same solution, but is not compiled until runtime.

Has anyone successfully gotten this working? Thanks!

reproduction: https://gist.github.com/toraora/a9d4eb8679383fe659da04d3be5c2d6e (I'll put up the actual solution when I finish setting up SSH keys on this machine)

Comment: Would you mind posting a minimal example to reproduce the problem? Sure, I could write it myself, but I'm lazy :-)

Comment: reproduction posted!

Comment: The problem is easy to spot: your only use of `srcfile` is in `File.ReadAllText`. Since you don't provide Roslyn with any way to know what the source file is, there is no way that Roslyn can generate debug info that allows that source file to be found. The solution is not so obvious for someone not too familiar with Roslyn's APIs though.

Answer (score 9):

Ah, so the solution was to have:

`CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText(srcfile), path: srcfile, encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)`

Thanks @hvd!